# Interpreting steep histogram, fitting distribution

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, fitting, histogram

I'm trying  to fit the distribution to the data. I started with histogram. Note that y axis is in logarithmic scale since the histogram is very steep. 
[image: histogram]
<sub>(source: [mimuw.edu.pl](http://siekiera.mimuw.edu.pl/~paal/histo.png))</sub>

How should proceed to find actual distribution. Should I modify my data first?
Any guesses what could the actual distribution be?

Comment: Note that histograms are not great, in general, for assessing distributions. See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram).

Comment: This is definitely a question for _Cross Validated_ (CV). Actually, there are many answers to similar questions here, so it most likely will be declared a _duplicate_. To the OP: I suggest you to search CV for similar questions and answers. As a starting point, check references (especially, the first one) in my [related CV answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143128/31372).

Comment: You cannot "proceed to find the actual distribution" from a sample. For any given distribution that might be a reasonable fit, there will be an infinite number of other distributions that are arbitrarily close to it. Distribution choice should be based on more than just the appearance of a histogram. Why do you need to identify a distribution?